# MVC5 ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create the membership tables on my existing SQL server 2008 Database and use that instead of the default database created for me in Visual Studio, but getting error when registering an account.  Is there a way to create the tables manually like with aspnet_regsql before?

Error:
The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

I figured out the answer.  The applicationUser does not like using connectionstring created by the database first approach.  You need to use standard connection string.

Comment: Is this table the same schema as the generated one? Are we just talking about a connection string change here? Keeping code first or moving to DbFirst?

Comment: I already have a database with existing tables on my sql server 2008. I have created the connection for it already.  Everything is fine, except when I try to register an account, it errors and will not create the tables in my database on sql server.

Comment: The existing table contains tables in it already.  It should just create the additional membership tables, but getting error.

Answer (score 5):

In Your IdentityModel.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

In WebConfig, use 2 different connection strings, one for ApplicationDbContext, and 
they other for your database first .edmx setup:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"                 connectionString="data source=(local); Initial Catalog=StoreDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;" />


<add name="StoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.StoreDB.csdl|    res://*/Models.StoreDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.StoreDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection     string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=STOREDB;integrated     security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: thank you sir!!!!! struggled for awhile as to why the database first approach with an .edmx file was not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few more details that will be helpful:

I was having this same problem. I’m doing database first development with an EDMX file. If you are using the connection string generated when adding the EDMX file in :base(“EDMXConnString”) you will most likely have this problem.

I fixed this by creating a standard connection string that pointed to the database where the ASP.NET Identity tables are.

```
<add name="MyConnString" connectionString="Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=db_name; User ID=user_id; Password=password; Connect Timeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And then used that connection string in :base, and it worked!

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnString")
    {
    }
}
```